# How to write a file in csv file with string in one column and bytes in another column

Tags: python

I have written a program which converts .jpg image into base64. Now I want to write these on a csv file. So that one column has a file name(string) the other column has the converted image (bytes). How do I achieve that. So far I have written below codes.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import base64
import csv

def main():
    array=[]
    pic_name=[]
    #opens file in listed directory
    for f in os.listdir('./jpg_Images'):
        if f.endswith('.jpg'):
            #making a list of a filename
            pic_name.append(f)
            #joining the path
            xpath = os.path.join ('./jpg_Images',f)
            #open .jpg file in Binary mode
            image = open(xpath, 'rb')
            #open binary file in read mode
            image_read = image.read()
            #encode the image
            image_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(image_read)
            #making the list of encoded image
            array.append(image_64_encode)

    with open('convert.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(zip(array, pic_name))
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that when you open a file using with open, it ensures the file to be closed after its scope. So you don't need f.close()

Comment: base64 encoding turns bytes into a string, so you're not mixing the two types.

Comment: I think the question is not precise. What needs to be done here? What's the question? Are you getting errors? How can we help? Also I suggest you change the function's name from 'main' to some other name.

Comment: So My question is when I am writing it into a csv file I am getting \n after every new line. Also Am i doing it right the way I am combining two data type in one csv file?

Comment: BTW, you should close your image files after reading them, or open them in a `with` statement so they get closed automatically. On a related note, you shouldn't manually close the CSV file, since you open it using `with`. It won't hurt anything to close a closed file, it's just redundant.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestion. I will make the changes as you guys have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily base64 encoded byte strings can be decoded to unicode with no loss of fidelity.  base64 decodes to printable (and non-escaped) characters from the ASCI range.  Simple change the line:

```
array.append(image_64_encode)
```

to:

```
array.append(image_64_encode.decode())
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried changing it to as you suggested. And i am trying to open the csv file in excel. The data in the file looks messed up. Is it because the encoded bytes are two big so that the excel is trying to compress it?